# Remote Image working on local react instance failing on Heroku

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, mongoose

My local app, a React, Express, and Mongoose App, has a blog post function where you can input in a text field a URL or remote image web destination and it saves in the directory location `/app/server/public/images/`. The image will be resized and displayed on the show page of the blog.

The code to my `PostCreateWidgit.js` is below:

```
renderAddForm() {
    return (
      <Style>
        {this.componentStyles}
        <div className="form-content">
          <h3 className="form-title"><FormattedMessage id="createNewPost" /></h3>
          {
            this.props.addPostError ?
              (<div className="error-message">{this.props.addPostError}</div>) : (<i></i>)
          }
          <input type="text" placeholder={this.props.intl.messages.postTitle} className="form-field" ref="title" defaultValue="" />
          <div className="image-preview-block">
            <label>
              <input type="text" placeholder={this.props.intl.messages.image} className="form-field" ref="preview_image" />
              <a href="#" className="waves-effect waves-light btn btn-small" id="select-preview-file" onClick={this.uploadPreview}>
                <FormattedMessage id="select_file" />
              </a>
            </label>
            <form style={{ display: 'none' }} ref="uploadPreviewForm" id="uploadPreviewForm" action="/upload" method="post" encType="multipart/form-data">
              <input name="image" type="file" id="uploadPreview" />
            </form>
          </div>
          <label>
            {this.props.intl.messages.postContent}
            {this.renderTinyMce('')}
          </label>
          <a className="post-submit-button waves-effect waves-light btn btn-small" href="#" onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.addPost(); }}>
            <FormattedMessage id="submit" /> <i className="material-icons right">send</i>
          </a>
          <a className="waves-effect waves-light btn red btn-small" href="#" onClick={(e) => { e.preventDefault(); this.toggleForm(); }}>
            <FormattedMessage id="cancel" />
          </a>
        </div>
      </Style>
    );
}
```

However, when I deploy to Heroku and attempt to create a blog post with a URL image I get this error message:

```
Cannot save downloaded image: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open'/app/server/public/images/user_4567c1b46e2b715a37167c6a8a90bd44/5772c8d744198e3cdabef632136ce645.jpg
```

What would be causing it to work on my local production instance, but failing on my Heroku app? I checked the help and FAQs on Heroku, but I did not see anything for React which is a language I am new to.

Comment: is `/app/server/public/...` publicly accessible?

Comment: Hi Daniel, how would I test that?

Comment: One thing you can try is to access it with your browser. watch for the response codes you get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a good chance that this is being caused because the directory you're trying to save to doesn't exist.

However, even if you can resolve the immediate error, you probably won't see the behaviour you expect on Heroku. That's because [its filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) and so any changes you make will be lost whenever your dynos restart. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

The [official recommendation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3) is to [store uploaded files on a third-party service like Amazon S3](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-node).